# Running Istanbul from npm scripts misses tests

Tags: npm, istanbul

If I run the following command directly from the terminal, I see that I have 233 tests run.

`./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register --require ./coffee-coverage-loader.js --require lib/bootstrap.coffee test/lib/**/*.coffee`

However, if I set that as a script in my `package.json` like:

`"coverage": "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register --require ./coffee-coverage-loader.js --require lib/bootstrap.coffee test/lib/**/*.coffee"`

and run `npm run coverage` I only see that 74 tests have run.

My tests are in `test/lib/**/*.coffee`.

Why does running the command through `npm` cause it to run less tests?

I have noticed that the tests that are not running are in `test/lib/*/*/*.coffee`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding quotes around the glob pattern in the `npm` script:

`"coverage": "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register --require ./coffee-coverage-loader.js --require lib/bootstrap.coffee './test/lib/**/*.coffee'"`

I am not sure why I had to put `./test/lib/**/*.coffee` in quotes to make it work though.